# HammerJS Pinch zoom reversed

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm currently working on a web app and want to add zoom functionality to it. However the HammerJS pinch scale is going the wrong way.

I have tried calculating the differance between the scales to determine if they are going in or out, but it does not feel smooth enough and kinda laggy.

```
//This is what I am using right now, it works but it is not going the direction I want, however it feels very smooth.
var scale = (e.scale * lastZoom);

//I have tried something like this, trying to use the velocity and adding it to the scale, this works for both in and out but it feels very laggy
var scale += Math.abs(velocity);
```

Here is a full list of the variables the pinch event returns, which variables are of value here?

```
{pointers: Array(2), changedPointers: Array(1), pointerType: "touch", srcEvent: PointerEvent, isFirst: false, …}
additionalEvent: "pinchout"
angle: 0
center: {x: 178, y: 252}
changedPointers: [PointerEvent]
deltaTime: 115
deltaX: -2
deltaY: 0
direction: 1
distance: 0
eventType: 1
isFinal: false
isFirst: false
maxPointers: 2
offsetDirection: 2
overallVelocity: -0.017391304347826087
overallVelocityX: -0.017391304347826087
overallVelocityY: 0
pointerType: "touch"
pointers: []
preventDefault: ƒ ()
rotation: -358.5997411736357
scale: 1.001221903381003
srcEvent: PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 3, width: 1.0986328125, height: 1.0986328125, pressure: 1, …}
target: canvas#map
timeStamp: 1549011830464
type: "pinch"
velocity: 0
velocityX: 0
velocityY: 0
```

So basically, I want to reverse the pinch event to zoom in when you pinch out and zoom out when you pinch in.